# How to write a sign_in failure test in test unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

I am using devise gem for authentication and I need to test the log-in failure test when a user gives wrong password and I am using factories too. Can anyone help me in writing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see this to get started with testing:

http://www.hiringthing.com/2012/08/17/rails-testing-factory-girl.html

and

http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures

Comment: I have everything in my factories but the thing is for devise sign_in failure case am not able to write test.I didn get where to write the test and how to write..